# How to call a function for specific objects in a C++ Array?

Tags: c++, inheritance, methods, hierarchy

I hope you can help me because I'm trying to improve my C++ inheritance concepts. First of all, I have the following object hierarchy:

A base class "Image" with two child classes: PNG and JPG (each one with their methods).

I wrote a method inside PNG class which (in a simulated way) deletes alpha channel (it just prints "Alpha channel deleted").

That being said, I want to write a method which takes an array of many pointers to image objects (can be either JPG or PNG) as input, and deletes the alpha channel of only those which are PNG. Since it isn't a good practice in C++ ask for the type of the object (or so I believe), which is the best way to loop through the image array (remembering that it could be filled with either PNG or JPG objects) and delete the alpha channel of only the PNG objects? In which class should I write that method? Parent or child?

I hope I've explained myself correctly, and thank you very much in advance.

Comment: virtual method that does nothing by default and reimplemented in the PNG child class. That's the whole point of virtual methods.

Comment: Note that you can't use an array of **objects** for this; you have to use an array of **pointers**.

Comment: You are right, thanks, I've just edited it :D @PeteBecker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious implementation is that the base class has a virtual method for deleting the alpha channel that is a no-op.  The PNG class inherits from Image and overrides this member function.

```
class Image
{
public:
    virtual void DeleteAlphaChannel() {};
};


class PNG : public Image
{
   void DeleteAlphaChannel() override
   {
      cout << "Alpha Channel deleted" << endl;
   }
};
```

Then a helper function that takes an *array* of *Image pointers*, hence `Image**`

```
void DeleteAlphaChannelsFromArrayOfObjects(Image** imageList, int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        imageList[i]->DeleteAlphaChannel();
    }
}
```

And corresponding sample code.

```
{
    PNG pngFile("foo.png");
    JPG jpgFile("bar.jpg");

    Image* imageList[2] = {&pngFile, &jpgFile};
    DeleteAlphaChannelsFromArrayOfObjects(imageList, 2);
}
```

You could also do a vector style implementation:

```
void DeleteAlphaChannelsFromArrayOfObjects(std::vector<Image*>& imageList)
{
    for (Image* pImage : images)
        pImage->DeleteAlphaChannel();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, great explanation ^^